# How to install extensions in Magento on SSH

Tags: magento, ssh, centos

How do I install a Connect 2.0 extension to my local development box without using the /downloader UI? How can I script this in a deployment routine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rm -rf var/cache var/session
chmod 550 ./mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable 
/*This link you get from Magento Connect*/
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
rm -rf var/cache var/session
chmod 550 ./mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable 
/*This link you get from Magento Connect*/
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```